# CanCan - Undefined method find for specific class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a controller named Administrator. This controller has actions to anothers models. When I try to authorize this actions with CanCan I get this response.

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in AdministratorController#preproduct_delete
</h1>
<pre>undefined method `find' for Administrator:Class</pre>
```

The controller code begins with:

```
class AdministratorController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def users
    authorize! :users, "Users List"
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

The ability model has:

```
if user.admin? then :admin
    can :users
end
```

The `authenticate_user!` method:

```
# See ControllerAdditions#authorize! for documentation. 
def authorize!(action, subject, *args) 
  message = nil 
  if args.last.kind_of?(Hash) && args.last.has_key?(:message) 
    message = args.pop[:message] 
  end 
  if cannot?(action, subject, *args) 
    message ||= unauthorized_message(action, subject) 
    raise AccessDenied.new(message, action, subject) 
  end 
  subject 
end
```

I tried to remove load_and_authorize_resource from the controller, but when any action is called, CanCan redirects me to login page every time.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified the permission, what does can :user mean ? specify a permission, for all permissions use :manage.

```
if user.admin?
    can :manage, :users
end
```

Comment: Yes i try with can :manage, :all and get the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in AdministratorController#preproduct_delete
</h1>
```

Please paste preproduct_delete of AdministratorController

```
<pre>undefined method `find' for Administrator:Class</pre>
```

Is Administrator inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base ? if it doesn't have find is because is not.
it should be

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
```

The `authenticate_user!` method:

```
# See ControllerAdditions#authorize! for documentation. 
def authorize!(action, subject, *args) 
 ....
end
```

**THIS IS NOT** the authenticate_user! method, this is authorize! **very different**, you have before_filter authenticate_user! post this method here. Something is calling preproduct_delete.

Comment: I made some tests and the problem it's when CanCan gem wants to check de permissions for method. I think maybe it's because i have a controller (Administrator) using diferentes models like Preproduct, Product, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the class name needs to be explicitly set. In my example I had the comments resource nested under the thread resource, and I was writing the following in controller:

```
class Buy::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :thread
```

This gives me `undefined find method` error, because comment model was under the thread namespace. When I explicitly set it like the following it works.

```
class Buy::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :thread, class: Buy::Thread
```